# C# how to post data with specific submit name (ID)

Tags: c#, php

What i need is to post data and get result without browsing the page , the php page i should post to has an if statement checks if the post was through the submit button,
to make things more clear lets say i have this page

```html
<form action="test2.php" method="post" name="myphpform" onSubmit="return checkForm()"  >
<table border=0>
<tr>
    <td>Your Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="yname" size="50"    maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Your Email:</td> <td><input type="text" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Message:</td> <td><input type="text" name="message" size="50" maxlength="50" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Are you a human being?</td>
    <td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submitname" value="submitvalue" /></td>


 if ($_POST["submitname"]) 
 {
  //echo "Post succeeded";
 }
```

now if i use any method to post data to that page i get response with the page body itself not the "Post succeeded" Msg, when i changed the condition to

```
 if ($_POST)
   {
      //echo "Post succeeded";
   }
```

i get the succeeded msg

this is the method i am using

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
string PostData = "Post Test data";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
os.Close();
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

i wanna know is there a way to post the data and trigger the if statement ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether `$_POST['submitname']` exists and has a "meaningful" value, so you need to set this parameter in the post with its name, something like this:

```
string PostData = "submitname=Post Test data";
```

and if you'd like to add any more parameters to the `POST` body, you could do it like that:

```
PostData += "&another=some other value";
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was great help, now if i may ask again what if that submit button has 2 values like this
    <form method="POST" action="test2.php" style="display: inline;">
   <input type="hidden" value="1132346097"  name="site" />
</noscript><br /><input type="submit" value="clickhere" name="27669698afedf2ed36d2d411ef13fc5a"><br /><br />

what will be the PostData ?